# Android Alarm not getting set

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I tried running this code through eclipse in my android device.
But it doesnt set the alarm.
Android permission  has been added.
What may be the issue !

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);

Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, AlarmAction.class);
PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, intent, 0);

this.alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingintent);
```

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/setting-up-alarm-using-alarmmanager-and-waking-up-screen-and-unlocking-keypad-on-alarm-goes-off-in-android/